# Change the ngModel value from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using AngularJS and I created a directive that requires 'ngModel':

```
'use strict';
angular.module('spot.im.embed').directive('sayBox', ['$sce', '$timeout', '$parse',
    function($sce, $timeout, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
            },
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$viewValue = 'adasd';
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

For reasons I don't know, the ng-model changes doesn't impact the view. Why is that? Is this the right way to change the ngModel value from a directive?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**$viewValue** is property, **$setViewValue** is method that you are probably looking for

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$setViewValue('adasd');
    ngModel.$render(); // depends – if you want update input value or only model value in the scope
}
```

### `$setViewValue(value, trigger);`

> This method should be called when an input directive want to change the view value; typically, this is done from within a DOM event handler.

documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: Should I call $render() myself? Why ngModel doesn't call to $render?

Comment: Yes, you should call `$render()`, try to run code http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/e00jdrsd/ . It is hard for me to write any suggestions without more context. What you are trying to resolve?

Answer (score 4):

It does not impact view, because `$viewValue` is updated on next digest cycle before it is displayed.

If you need to change view value not touching model value - you can do this using `$formatters` from NgModelController, and `$parsers` to update model value from view value ([ngModel controller documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)).

```
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
  ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value){
    return 'adasd';
  });
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gZslSeVa2Frq0edEbuWK?p=preview

---

**UPD:**

If you need to update model value directly (not just format value for displaying or parse user input), you can use `$setViewValue` (as it was mentioned in Krzysztof Safjanowski answer).

Other way to modify model value is to use data binding for isolated scope:

```
scope: {
    ngModel:'='
},
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
  scope.ngModel= 'adasd';
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/l9kEU03OwI03uVUc6AQ0?p=preview

If you are not using isolated scope it also posible to update model value, using `$parse` service:

```
 link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
   $parse(iAttrs.ngModel).assign(scope, 'adasd');
 }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BDsaBxqgs9kJjnj8TsSz?p=preview

Comment: Formatters doesn't update the value. They tells how to format it.

Comment: @Naor Updated an answer with ways to change a model value from directive